# Simple Java Web validation Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'number' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, http, web

I have a problem on validating a simple "NumberValidate" Object

Here you see the JSP file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Vul een nummer in:</h1>
        <form:form action="form" modelAttribute="number" method="POST">
            <form:input path="number"/>
            <form:errors path="number"/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form:form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
package controller;

import domain.NumberValidate;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class ValidationController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"form"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHomePage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("number", new NumberValidate());
        return "validation";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = {"form"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showHomePage(@Valid @ModelAttribute NumberValidate number, BindingResult result){
        if(result.hasErrors())
            return "validation";
        return "success";
    }
}
```

The "NumberValidate" Class:

package domain;

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;


public class NumberValidate {
    @Min(50)
    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

When i run the application it starts normal with the textbox etc.
When I type a number less then 40 it gives the error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'number' available as request attribute

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `showHomePage` method, change to `@ModelAttribute("number")` and:

```
if(result.hasErrors()) {
    return "validation";
}
return "success";
```

Answer (score 0):

if validation has error then you need to add **number** attribute in model when returning to **validation** view. Code snippet is below :

`@RequestMapping(value = {"form"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showHomePage(@Valid @ModelAttribute NumberValidate number, BindingResult result){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("number", number);
            return "validation";
       }
        return "success";
    }`